# SqlDataReader to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, sql, list

I'm trying to write a method that retrieves a collection of type T for a query that returns a **single column** of values.

What I've tried so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteReader<T>(string query)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while (reader.Read()) 
               { 
                   yield return (T)reader[0]; 
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample usage:

```
foreach (var dbname in ExecuteReader<string>("SELECT Name FROM sys.databases"))
{
    //iterate db names
}
```

Problem is now I'd like to add error handling to the code with **try/catch**, something like:

```
try
{
    //my code
}
catch
{
   //Error handling code
   return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

However **yield return is not compatible with try/catch**.

I've seen some alternatives on the web such as writing an extension for the IDataReader class but I feel like they could be outdated, so I'm open to suggestions or better ways to achieve this.

EDIT:

I feel like the answers are deviating from the question itself, maybe I didnt make myself clear. the **try-catch** or the **yield** **are not relevant** to me, this is simply a minor obstacle I found after writing my code.

*What I wanted to know is if this is the right way of populating a list from a datareader where a single column of generic type is retrieved.*

Comment: So dont use yield, and put all to list, then return list.

Comment: Note that `try {} catch { return Enumerable.Empty<T>()}` is _not_ error handling.

Comment: @Evk that was merely an example, I also want to register the error messages into some logs

Comment: Why do you want to add the try-catch inside this method? Why not higher up the stack?

Comment: @jeroenh because then if I have several parts of my code calling this method I would have to implement the try-catch clause separately for each one of them... or is this the intended usage?

Comment: I think if you want to keep yield - you have to unwrap usings to try-finally and check exceptions separately. That is - check if cn.Open throws, check if ExecuteReader throws and so on. So that yield statement itself is not inside try-catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this method private and create a public method with the same signature that calls into the private method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteReader<T>(string query)
{
    try{
        return executeReader<T>(query);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // your handling code here
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> executeReader<T>(string query)
{
    // same code as you have above in your example

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn.ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while (reader.Read()) 
               { 
                   yield return (T)reader[0]; 
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could not catch it at all and let the caller worry about the Exception. You could also write the code in such a way that there are many `try/catch` blocks but the `yield` is never found in one as @Evk suggested.

Comment: yes, this is a valid workaround, I will consider it as a valid answer later if I do not receive more satisfacting alternatives.

Comment: I just want to add that the point of my question wasn't to understand why yield cannot be used with try-catch, so it is a bit infuriating to get my question flagged as duplicate for that

Comment: @Innat3 - I just now saw your edit. I think it was not very clear because the last non-code 1/2 of your question focused on the problem with `yield` and `try/catch`.